# Is there an equivalent view binding annotation similar to @DataBound?

Tags: android, annotations, android-databinding

Using Android Annotations, you can specify @DataBound for an enhanced activity/fragment (@EActivity/@EFragment).  This inflates your activity/fragment using databinding and creates a dataViewBinding object.

Is there an equivalent for only using ViewBinding rather than DataViewBinding?

@BindingObject only returns a DataViewBinding object.

Comment: @DataBound, "enhanced activity" what are you talking about. Can you link me to the documentation?

Comment: https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-activities

Comment: https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Data-binding-support